# Android gradle plugin tool outdated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:(1, 0) The android gradle plugin version 2.3.0-alpha1 is too
>   old, please update to the latest version.
>
> To override this check from the command line please set the
>   ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to
>   "7e7deaebeebf38c3d877c687336265b8c39674f5"

Any idea what Gradle plugin version I should use? I'm using Android Studio 2.3 Beta 1 in canary channel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gradle plugin version should be 2.3.0-beta1.

Comment: Thanks! It Worked.

Comment: For future reference, gradle plugin versions available at: https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle